# Can a 32-bit system be upgraded to a 64-bit?

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, operating-systems

The question is fairly self explanatory.

I have a 5-year-old computer running 32-bit Windows XP. I have an install disk for 64-bit Windows 7. Can I upgrade my operating system despite the bit differences?

Comment: Short answer: No.

Comment: Depends if your computer has 64 bit support

Comment: one thing to watch out for is that if you are upgrading XP to windows 7, the "upgrade" version is cheaper but will only allow you to install the version for the architecture you had installed before. that is, if you had XP 32bit,even if your CPU supports 64 bit the upgrade version will only install the 32 bit version. if it were 64 previously then it would install 64 again. the full version doesn't seem to have this limitation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if your CPU is 64 bit capable. You can find your CPUs model# in My Computer's properties, then search a site like [CPU World](http://www.cpu-world.com) to find out.

Answer (score 6):

Define "Upgrade".

If you mean an actual upgrade, keeping your settings in place, then... no - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd772579%28v=ws.10%29.aspx - not just because cross-architecture upgrades are not possible, but because there is no direct upgrade path from Windows XP to Windows 7.

If by "Upgrade" you mean a clean install, not an in-place upgrade, then that depends on the capabilities of your computer. But on a 5-year-old desktop I would question the usefulness of a 64-bit operating system anyway, so there is probably nothing for you to gain from moving to 64-bit anyway.

Comment: In 2009 a majority of the systems sold were 64-bit. Please be aware that in most countries of the world, a 5yo computer **is** new.

Comment: @kinokijuf - I said nothing about it being not new; nor did I pass any judgement for having a 5 year old computer. The *newest* thing in my computer at home is from 2009. But unless the op has over 4GB of RAM in their system, and most PC's from 2009 didn't, then don't just upgrade your architecture for the sake of it.

Comment: Also, there is an upgrade path from XP to 7 if you have a Vista disc at hand.

Answer (score 1):

What is your processor?

If your processor supports x64 instructions, you should be able to install 64-bit Windows. However, you will lose all of your programs and files, so you should make a backup before you do so.

Answer (score 1):

If you install [Belarc Advisor](http://www.belarc.com/free_download.html), it will produce a computer profile for you, and tell you if your processor is 64-bit capable.

> The Belarc Advisor builds a detailed profile of your installed
>   software and hardware, network inventory, missing Microsoft hotfixes,
>   anti-virus status, security benchmarks, and displays the results in
>   your Web browser. All of your PC profile information is kept private
>   on your PC and is not sent to any web server.